# JavaScript showing only last result

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print the years in which Sunday comes in 1<sup>st</sup> January. The problem is that it's only showing the last result.

```js
function sun() {
  var sunday = new Date();
  var year;
  for (year = "2014"; year <= 2050; year++) {
    var date = new Date(year, 0, 1);
    if (date.getDay() == 0)
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "First Jan being sunday on year =" + year + "<br>";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="sun()">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put "January 1st will be on Sunday in:" statically inside the '#demo' `div`, then concatenate the years by using `+=` instead of `=`, *e.g.*:

```js
function sun() {
  for (let year = 2014; year <= 2050; year++) {
    if ((new Date(year, 0, 1)).getDay() == 0) {
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += " " + year;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="sun()">
<div id="demo">January 1st will be on Sunday in:</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The values are getting replaced in each iteration of the loop.

Concatenating the result is going to help.

Use the operator + in the expression:

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += "First Jan being sunday on year ="+year+"<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Add + to your expression

```
 document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += "First Jan being sunday on year ="+year+"<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function sun(){

var sunday = new Date();
var year;

for (year = "2014"; year <= 2050; year++){
    var date = new Date(year,0,1);
    if (date.getDay()==0)
    //you are overwriting the content of 'demo' each time, changed to "+=" so it adds new HTML each time
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += "First Jan being sunday on year ="+year+"<br>"; 
}
```

}

Comment: Glad we could help.